# Randomizing a long array with only unique digits

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I'm trying to make a long array composed of the digits 0 - 9 in a random order, meaning there would be no duplicates of the same digit. I'm a novice coder, and this is what I tried to come up with.

```
    public static void shuffle() 
{
    long[] rn = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int n;
        n = rand.nextInt(10) + 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
        {
            if (n != rn[j]) 
            {
               j++; 
            }
            else if (n == rn[j]) 
            {

                n = rand.nextInt(10) + 0;
                if (j > 0) 
                {
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        rn[i] = n;
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) 
    {
        System.out.print(rn[l]);
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

By my understanding, this shouldn't let any duplicate digits pass, yet it does. Did I do something wrong?

PS: I'm not allowed to use collections or array lists. I'm using the Ready To Program IDE which apparently doesn't support those.

Comment: I tried to add the Java tag, because it may help you get solutions from people who know that language better, but your post already has 5 tags :)

Comment: @versvs Good suggestion, changed shuffle to java

Comment: What are these '+0;' good for? Is it some voodoo?

Comment: Is it for some coding exercise or homework? Are you allowed to use Java collection framework in your implementation? Because if you are, the most obvious thing would be just to use Set to assemble your random values

Comment: Flawed algorithm from the start. You don't want random numbers at all, you want the numbers 0..9 in random order. So fill the array with 0..9, then *shuffle* it with a simple Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker This was just an experiment, I've created a new code doing what you described.

Answer (score 0):

So second one. There are many flaws in it.

You should never change your for variable inside of your code only when you really know what you do.

```
if (n != rn[j]){
    j++; 
}
```

That is wrong => you will skip a few elements because you already increase the variable in the for loop. So in each iteration you increase it +2.

But because you want to check all other elements from the beginning again when one test failed you have to put in the else part j=-1.
Why -1? Because in the last step of the for loop the for loop will increase it by 1 so you will start with 0 again.

```
j = -1;
```

When you change the one above so that you don't increase it you will run into a never ending loop. 
The reason is, that you are prefilling it with zeros. Would you fill it with 10 or some other numbers (not 0-9) it won't happen.
So one way is to fill the array with other numbers or only check the first i numbers you have filled with random numbers:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

In the end this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int n;
    n = rand.nextInt(10);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    {
        if (n == rn[j]) 
        {

            n = rand.nextInt(10);
            j = -1;
        }
    }
    rn[i] = n;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I didn't notice this. However, the problem persists even after I changed it to convert j to 0 instead of it being decremented. Is there something else that I missed...?

Comment: true i looked over it saw some more flaws let me rewrite my solution.

Comment: Hi, I changed the else if to just an if, but that gave me an out of bounds exception, so I changed the for loop to be j < 9; instead of j < 10;. This worked, but there is only max one duplicate of a digit now. No idea how to solve that 1 duplicate digit.

Comment: Not sure why this happens but yeah I showed you the flaws you had in your code in my solution. Try to understand it. In 300 runs there were no duplicate in the array. (calculated the sum to test it, should be equal 45)

Comment: You like the `+ 0;` too - is it some Random-voodoo? :)

Comment: not really I don't understand why he does it. Copy paste fragment. I will remove it.

Comment: the +0 was there to make a random number between 0 and 10, didn't know it wasn't needed.

Comment: On that note, I have one last question if possible: How do I stop java from removing a 0 if it's the first digit in the number? It's needed for the specific bit of code I'm doing, since the user needs to make it be in the front using number reversals.

Comment: I understand your question. 
But do you mean that you want 01? or something? Then you have to use String not number. Because 01 == 1. (Math magic)

Answer (score -1):

You are indeed doing some peculiar things.

- **Changing the loop variable** — Most of the time, one should only modify the loop variable (`i` and `j` in your case) when some serious magic is needed, otherwise, the loop variable should be left alone.
- **Voodooish `+ 0`** — Adding 0 to a value is pointless.

Regarding your shuffle method, I'm proposing a whole other approach. You have a loop within a loop, so the execution time will exponentially increase when the array is larger.

Instead, one could also select a random *index* from the source array, and then fill the next position of the new array with that value. Of course, in order to avoid a value from the source array to be picked twice, we will swap that value with the value on the last position of the source array and decrement its size.

```
index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  |
value | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 |
arraySize: 5

Step 1. Pick random index, where index is less than arraySize
(in this example index 1 has been picked)

index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  4 |
value | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 |
arraySize: 5
pickedIndex: 1

Step 2. Swap value at pickedIndex with value at index arraySize − 1

index | 0 |  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
value | 2 | 11 | 5 | 7 | 3 |
arraySize: 5

Step 3. Decrease array size, so the value previously on the picked
position won't be picked again

index | 0 |  1 | 2 | 3 |
value | 2 | 11 | 5 | 7 |
array size: 4
```

The code looks like this:

```
private static int[] shuffle(int[] array) {
    int[] availableNumbers = new int[array.length];
    int availableNumbersLength = availableNumbers.length;
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, availableNumbers, 0, array.length);
    int[] shuffledArray = new int[availableNumbers.length];

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < availableNumbers.length; i++) {
        int index = r.nextInt(availableNumbersLength);
        shuffledArray[i] = availableNumbers[index];
        availableNumbers[index] = availableNumbers[availableNumbersLength - 1];
        availableNumbersLength--;
    }
    return shuffledArray;
}
```

Note that I copied the input array so that the source array is left unchanged and a new array containing the elements in a random order, is returned. You could also, of course, shuffle the original array.

Comment: In step 2/3 the value for index 1 should be 5 not 3 right? Otherwise you don't shuffle.